# JOIN COM 3 TABELAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho 3 Tabelas as quais quero trazer apenas dados da tabela 1, caso não tenha na tabela 1 trazer os dados da tabela 3 , se tiver dados nas 3 tabela trazer apenas da tabela 3.
O meu problema é que quando tenho os dados nas 2 tabelas esta trazendo duplicado, pois traz os dados da tabela 1 e tabela 3.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT B.CodigoPasta AS Pasta, B.Tipo_Acao as TipoAcao, SUM(B.ValorNB) AS Valor, G.Usuario, G.DataCriacao  FROM TB_Contrato AS B
INNER JOIN TB_Processamento AS A
ON B.Id = A.IdContrato
LEFT JOIN TB_StatusNegociacao AS G
    ON G.IdProcessamento = A.Id 
GROUP BY B.CodigoPasta,B.Tipo_Acao,G.Usuario,G.DataCriacao
ORDER BY g.DataCriacao desc
```

Comment: Tentou usar apenas Left Join para ver se ele obriga a pelo menos um result?

Comment: Coloquei da forma abaixo porém ainda continua repetindo o B.codigoPasta             SELECT DISTINCT B.CodigoPasta AS Pasta, B.Tipo_Acao as TipoAcao, SUM(B.ValorNB) AS Valor, G.Usuario, G.DataCriacao  FROM TB_Contrato AS B
LEFT JOIN TB_Processamento AS A
ON B.Id = A.IdContrato
LEFT JOIN TB_StatusNegociacao AS G
 ON G.IdProcessamento = A.Id 
GROUP BY B.CodigoPasta,B.Tipo_Acao,G.Usuario,G.DataCriacao
ORDER BY g.DataCriacao desc